# How to properly add .NET assemblies to Powershell session?

Tags: powershell, .net

I have a .NET assembly (a dll) which is an API to backup software we use here. It contains some properties and methods I would like to take advantage of in my Powershell script(s). However, I am running into a lot of issues with first loading the assembly, then using any of the types once the assembly is loaded.

The complete file path is:

```
C:\rnd\CloudBerry.Backup.API.dll
```

In Powershell I use:

```
$dllpath = "C:\rnd\CloudBerry.Backup.API.dll"
Add-Type -Path $dllpath
```

I get the error below:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -Path $dllpath
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeComma
ndAdd-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Using the same cmdlet on another .NET assembly, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), which has examples of using the same functionality on the site also does not work for me.

I eventually find that I am seemingly able to load the assembly using reflection:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)
```

Although I don't understand the difference between the methods Load, LoadFrom, or LoadFile that last method seems to work.

However, I still seem to be unable to create instances or use objects. Each time I try, I get errors that describe that Powershell is unable to find any of the public types.

I know the classes are there:

```
$asm = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)
$cbbtypes = $asm.GetExportedTypes()
$cbbtypes | Get-Member -Static
```

---- start of excerpt ----

```
   TypeName: CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupProvider

Name                MemberType Definition
----                ---------- ----------
PlanChanged         Event          System.EventHandler`1[CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.Utils.ChangedEventArgs] PlanChanged(Sy...
PlanRemoved         Event          System.EventHandler`1[CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.Utils.PlanRemoveEventArgs] PlanRemoved...
CalculateFolderSize Method     static long CalculateFolderSize()
Equals              Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
GetAccounts         Method     static CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.Account[],     CloudBerry.Backup.API, Version=1.0.0.1, Cu...
GetBackupPlans      Method     static CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupPlan[], CloudBerry.Backup.API, Version=1.0.0.1,...
ReferenceEquals     Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
SetProfilePath      Method     static System.Void SetProfilePath(string profilePath)
```

----end of excerpt----

Trying to use static methods fail, I don't know why!!!

```
[CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupProvider]::GetAccounts()
Unable to find type [CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupProvider]: make sure that the     assembly containing this type is load
ed.
At line:1 char:42
+ [CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupProvider] <<<< ::GetAccounts()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupProvider:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Any guidance appreciated!!

Answer (score 19):

Could you surround the `Add-Type` with a try catch and print the LoaderExceptions property, as the error is stating to do. It may provide an exception with a more detailed error message.

```
try
{
    Add-Type -Path "C:\rnd\CloudBerry.Backup.API.dll"
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions | %
    {
        Write-Error $_.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't there a way to use relative path?

Comment: The opening curly bracket must be on the same line as the percent sign:
 `$_.Exception.LoaderExceptions | % {`

Comment: At the time of posting, which was I believe PS2.0? That was valid syntax. Has this changed in 6+? Asking for my own curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the methods above either did not work for me or were unclear.

Here's what I use to wrap -AddPath calls and catch LoaderExceptions:

```
try
{
   Add-Type -Path "C:\path\to.dll"
}
catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException]
{
   Write-Host "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
   Write-Host "StackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
   Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
}
```

**Reference**
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dff8487f-69af-4b64-ab83-13d58a55c523/addtype-inheritance-loaderexceptions

Answer (score 3):

I found this link:
http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html

He says, ".LoadWithPartialName" has been deprecated.  Therefore, instead of continuing to implement Add-Type with that method, it uses a static, internal table to translate the "partial name" to a "full name".  In the example given in the question, `CloudBerry.Backup.API.dll` does not have an entry in PowerShell's internal table, which is why `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath)` works.  It is not using the table to look up a partial name.

Answer (score 1):

The `LoaderExceptions` are hidden inside the error record. If the add-type error was the last one in the error list, use `$Error[0].InnerException.LoaderExceptions` to show the errors. Most likely, your library is dependent on another that has not been loaded. You can either `Add-Type` each one, or just make a list and use the `-ReferencedAssemblies` argument to `Add-Type`.

Comment: Try $Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions and following Eris's advise.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following setup to load a custom csharp control in powershell. It allows the control to be customized and utilized from within powershell.

here is the blog link

http://justcode.ca/wp/?p=435

and here is the codeproject link with source

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311705/Custom-CSharp-Control-for-Powershell

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

I guess by now you **MIGHT** have found an answer to this phenomena.
I ran upon this post after encountering the same problem...I could load the assembly, and view the types contained in the assembly, but was unable to instanciate a instance of it from a static class.  Was it EFTIDY. Tidy, EFTidyNet.TidyNet.Options or what?  Ooooo Weeee...Problems...problems...it could be anything.  And looking through the static methods and types of the DLL didn't reveal anything promising.  Now I was getting depressed.  I had it working in a compiled C# program, but for my use I wanted to have it running in a interpeted language...powershell.

My solution I found, and it's still being proven, but I'm elated and wanted to share this.  Build a small console.exe app exercising the func that I was interested in and then view it in something that would decompile it or show the IL code.  I used Red-Gate's reflector and the powershell language generator add-in and Wallah!  it showed what the proper constructor string was!  :-)    Try it. and I hope it works for whomever is faced with this problem.

Comment: And... what was the proper constructor string? This doesn't really answer the question the way it's written. Also, welcome to ServerFault!