# How to properly add .NET Core 3.1 assemblies to PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, dotnet-framework

Related to this question: [How to properly add .NET assemblies to Powershell session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/455163/how-to-properly-add-net-assemblies-to-powershell-session)

I used this code to likewise try to load a .NET Core 3.1 assembly into a PowerShell session.

I used this code:

```
# Load Assembly 

Add-Type -Path "I:\DW\tools\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\DataTools.dll" -PassThru

if ($Error.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host $Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions
}
```

and I got this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Vers
>   ion=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependenc
>   ies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Then I built my assembly with this command to make it "self-contained":

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained
```

However, now I am getting these `LoaderExceptions`:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because the parent does not exist.

Am I missing something in my `dotnet build` statement? or do I need to include an additional assembly?

NOTE: I also have dotnet 5 preview installed.

Comment: I think if I install PowerShell v7, then I can run dotnet core. That may solve my problem

Comment: It is; only .NET Standard 2.0 and earlier assemblies are .NET Framework compatible (what Windows PowerShell uses to run). In order to run any .NET Core or .NET Standard 2.1 or later assemblies you must run PowerShell Core built with a version of .NET Core that's greater or equal to the version used to build the assemblies you're using. TL;DR Run the latest version of PowerShell Core and you should be good.

Comment: Yes, upgrading from PowerShell 6 to PowerShell 7 solved this for me, too. Thank you so much! I don't think I would have figured this out from the error message.